# Can not connect to Amazon EC2 node server from browser

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

When I start node server inside my EC2, I am able to connect either by localhost(inside EC2) or directly by link(also inside EC2, e.g. http://ec2-18-217-243-129.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/).

But when I try to connect from different browser (from my main pc), I can't do it.
 I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`. I can't figure out why. Does somebody have any idea, how I can connect to my server? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like the security groups attached to that EC2 instance aren't allowing connections on port 80 from your IP address.

Comment: I've added custom rule for port 80 from any source, but error still appears

Comment: Does the instance have a public IP?

Comment: Yep, 18.217.243.129

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in firewall. It had been blocking inbound connections. I've been using Windows Server and after disabling firewall everything works fine.